# How do we find the sampling distribution of all possible samples?

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

The source of the question below is from Edgenuity's Statistics course.

> The times to pop a 3.4-ounce bag of microwave popcorn without burning it are Normally distributed with a mean time of 140 seconds and a standard deviation of 20 seconds. A random sample of four bags is selected and the mean time to pop the bags is recorded. Which of the following describes the sampling distribution of the sample mean?

> **A.** approximately Normal with a mean of 70 seconds and a standard deviation of 5 seconds
>
> **B.** approximately Normal with a mean 70 seconds and a standard deviation 20 seconds
>
> **C.** approximately Normal with a mean of 140 seconds and a standard deviation of 20 seconds
>
> **D.** approximately Normal with a mean of 140 seconds and a standard deviation of 10 seconds

Firstly, I would like *help* with this question, not the correct answer. Secondly, this question appeared like a no-brainer to me since the distribution is Normal, instead of skewed, the samples would represent similar statistical values of the population, and thus would have similar (or, in the case of the answer choices, the same) mean of 140 seconds and standard deviation of 20 seconds (C).

However, correct me if I'm wrong, the sample size of 4 may be an indicator to use a specific formula or a different method. If that is the case, I do not know which. If you believe my answer is incorrect, could you guide me on the beginning steps to find the correct answer?

**Edit:** The sampling distribution of the sample mean is found using the formula $μ\bar X=μ$, which, when substituted, equals $140 = 140$. The standard deviation of the sample mean would be found using the formula $σ\bar X=σ/√n$, which, when substituted, equals $σ\bar X=20/√4 = 10$. The correct answer, thus, is D.

Comment: The question, as posed, has no correct answer - it really should say **the sampling distribution of the sample mean** in the last sentence.

Comment: @Clarinetist I agree. I simply copied the question from the source. Would I also include "...and sample standard deviation" in your correction?

Comment: For this question, no - what you're specifically interested in what the distribution of the sample mean is. The sample standard deviation would follow an entirely different distribution (usually tackled in a more advanced class).

Comment: Your (now prior) edit is incorrect. The **sampling distribution of the sample mean** has mean $\mu_{\bar{X}} = \mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma_{\bar{X}} = \sigma/\sqrt{n}$. The sampling distribution of the sample standard deviation is something else entirely and is tackled in a more advanced class requiring calculus. See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2549724/81560 for information on the sampling distribution of the sample standard deviation.

Comment: @Clarinetist I see my mistake—it passed over my head when we just discussed it. In this case, would this be called "sample standard deviation"?

Comment: $\sigma_{\bar{X}}$ is not called the sample standard deviation; it is, rather, the standard deviation of the sample mean (or, if you want to use the wording of the question, "the standard deviation of the sampling distribution of the sample mean"). The point is this: if you have points being drawn from a normally-distributed population, a sample mean of size $n$ is normally distributed as well. Each normal distribution is uniquely determined by its mean and its standard deviation, hence you have the mean and standard deviation of the sampling distribution of the sample mean.

Comment: Note that I'm being extremely nitpicky and precise compared to what would usually be expected at a stats course at this level, but I want to make sure you're communicating the concepts correctly. If you want to completely understand what I'm describing to you, you'll need at least two semesters of calculus, a semester of probability with calculus, and then a semester of stats with calculus, which I know is well above the level of the course you're in.

Comment: @Clarinetist I understand. You are right, that is definitely above my level at the moment, which is likely why it is not grasping properly. Will keep it in mind for the future.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is not C. If $X$ is the time to pop a bag of popcorn, that would be C.

The question asks for the distribution of $\bar X$, which is composed of a sample of 4. Indeed $\bar X$ is a random variable with its own distribution, called a sampling distribution, because it is *based on the sample*; your task is to find its distribution.

Comment: Ah—understood. To find the samples' standard deviation, would I use the equation $σ\bar X=σ/√n$ and their mean using $μ\bar X=μ$?

Comment: Those are the correct formulas.